# How to parse the below json using Google GSON library?

Tags: java, android, gson

This is my json response which I am getting from server,

```
{
 "awards": [
    "31",
    "33",
    "44",
    "45",
    "46",
    "48"
 ]
}
```

but when I am trying to parse it using below code

```
@SerializedName("awards")
  private UserAwards[] awards;

  public class UserAwards {

  }
```

it's giving me following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 247.
```

please help me to find it how I can parse this.

Comment: `awards` is Json Array. show your complete code

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), If you're not able to do yourself json to object.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class UserAwards {

    @Expose
    @Valid
    private List<String> awards = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getAwards() {
        return awards;
    }

    public void setAwards(List<String> awards) {
        this.awards = awards;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for parsing:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(
                        FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
userAwards= gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.toString(), UserAwards.class);
```

and your class should look like

```
public class UserAwards{

    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> awards;
}
```

plus add set and get methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as below:

```
private void parseResponse(final Reader p_response) {
    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (p_response != null) {
                Gson m_gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy(
                        FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
                UserAwards m_details = m_gson.fromJson(p_response,
                        UserAwards.class);
                if (m_details != null) {

                      for (int i = 0; i < m_details.awards.length; i++) {
                        System.err.println("IDs======"
                                + m_details.awards[i].toString());
                        }
                    }
```

Also make your POJO class as below:

```
public class UserAwards {

     public List<String> awards = new ArrayList<String>();
 }
```